# Why is sed with 'g' modifier not replacing all matches

Tags: bash, sed

sed with 'g' modifier not replacing all matches.

Example:

```
$ sed -e 's:foo\([^\s]*\):\1 :g' <(echo "hey foobar foobar ")
```

Expected:

```
"hey bar bar"
```

Actual:

```
"hey bar foobar"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s` is a PCRE extension that POSIX `sed` isn't guaranteed to implement; and without it being honored, your match stops only at the letter `s` or at backslashes, not at spaces.

You get correct behavior if instead you use:

```
sed -re 's:foo([^[:space:]]*):\1 :g'
```

...or...

```
sed -e 's:foo\([^[:space:]]*\):\1 :g'
```

---

To better see what's going on for your self, you can change the replacement string to have sigils around it, to see exactly what is being captured:

```
$ sed -e 's:foo\([^\s]*\):<\1 >:g' <<<"hey foobar foobar "
hey <bar foobar  >
$ sed -e 's:foo\([^\s]*\):<\1 >:g' <<<"hey foobar foobar s foobar foobar "
hey <bar foobar  >s <bar foobar  >
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the `[^\s]*` -- this doesn't do what you think it does.   This will look for any character that doesn't match `\` or `s` (it doesn't expand `\s` to be any whitespace inside of a list -- see below)  Because there are no matches for this, it will match all of `foobar foobar`, and replace it with `bar foobar`.   Replace this with `[^ ]*` or better yet `\S*`

From [the gnu man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) (note other versions of sed may act differently)

> The characters $, *, ., [, and \ are normally not special within list.
> For example, [*] matches either ‘\’ or ‘*’, because the \ is not
> special here. However, strings like [.ch.], [=a=], and [:space:] are
> special within list and represent collating symbols, equivalence
> classes, and character classes, respectively, and [ is therefore
> special within list when it is followed by ., =, or :. Also, when not
> in POSIXLY_CORRECT mode, special escapes like \n and \t are recognized
> within list. See Escapes.

Comment: Note that you're quoting GNU-specific documentation. Other versions of `sed` may be POSIXly correct by default, as the OP hasn't specified a particular operating system (or, therefore, a particular version of `sed`).